# java and xml file not linking

Tags: android

I have been trying to make a Food recipes application on Android studio 2.1. But everytime i make a new project or open a old project, there's an error in "SetContentView" line showing that R can't be linked ( please see image attached)[image of problem in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymycs.jpg).Even i try to call ID's of buttons,webview,etc, there's an error in "R" part,which i think is due to fact that "res" is not getting linked to java file. I have tried following things but none worked and error is still there:

1. Downloaded Android studio 2.1 again from google.developers website
2. Cleaned and run project again.
3. Downloaded every tool in SDK manager except google play.
4. I have java SE 8u101 (latest and downloaded from oracle site).
5. Did gradle sync in project.
6. Checked respective xml files and it's error free.
7. same error is with every java file and every project made on this studio.

Same project is running without any error in "setContentView" line in Android Studio 1.2 version.Thanks.

Comment: Try to restart Android Studio.

Comment: Rebuild your project

Comment: I did it multiple times but same error is there

Comment: import your project's R file

Comment: i tried adding import.android.R above class line but after adding it same error was there

Comment: in other version while linking java and xml, activity name would appear automatically after R.layout and we just have to select it. But when import.android.R is done, no such thing happens

Comment: there can be n no. of reasons for this to happen.. make sure you have no errors in resource files (drawables, string, styles, layouts.. etc)..
clean, rebuild, restart studio..
check manifest for any error or so

Comment: Android Studio has the reference to the SDK to the correct folder? if yes i think the invalidate\restart cache is the best solution

Comment: `android.R` is not the correct import... It is `your.package.name.R`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your app's application ID is `com.example.intel`, add this line

```
import com.example.intel.R
```

`android.R` is not the correct import for *your* XML files.

If the R cannot be resolved, then you have an error in your XML files and it can't generate `R.java`

Comment: thanks, error is solved by starting a new project after downloading every tool in SDK manager.

Comment: SDK patch applierv1 and Android SDK tools 25.1.7 wasn't installed, so i installed them and started project again and it worked

Comment: Well, the build tool version has to match whats being used in Gradle. So you didn't literally download "every tool"?

Comment: Okay,i'll remember that if there's any similar kind of problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

delete your android.R import, then it will work